# Выбор БД для хранения и сравнения строк

Tags: база-данных

Имеется 500 млн строк,
Нужно сделать выбор в сторону качественной БД, чтобы можно было сравнивать новые строки в имеющейся огромной базе.

Справится ли быстро с этой задачей MySQL?

Comment: сравнивать - это что за операция? точное совпадение или расстояние между двумя строками?

Comment: вот перед Insert нужно сравнить прежде чем добавлять, а то будут дубликаты

Comment: Ну если на точное равенство - то все СУБД с этим отлично справляются

Comment: В любой СУБД есть MERGE-like запросы. В MySQL это `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: любое key-value хранилище

Comment: В том то и дело, что не все субд. Например Aerospike делает до 1 миллиона операций в секунду! Есть Hbase и Neo4j Графовая ну и MySql вот из этих выбираю, но мне кажется MySQL будет изрядно подтормаживать...

Comment: а вы не думали об использовании хэш-функции?

Comment: Спасибо, но Что вы подразумеваете?
Я лишь могу догадываться использовать хэш функции к одной из вышеперечисленных СУБД

Comment: Можно использовать индексы, тогда сравнение будет происходить быстрее. Про индексы в MySQL можно почитать на хабре https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/20246